# Net core MVC clean architecture without repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture, structure, clean-architecture, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to create a MVC application in net core 2.1 using the eshoponweb example application. Ive read that in entity Framework core there's no great benefit of putting a repository layer in and to just use the ef dbcontext directly. How would I do this in a clean architecture scenerio. In the example application the dB context is in the infrastructure layer and the business services logic is all in the application core. I thought about moving either of these but then won't that prevent the separation that clean architecture is looking to achieve. https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb and https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/

Comment: There is no great benefit to use Repository (or Unit of Work) with EF because it's already implemented (but without the naming conventions).  DbContext is Unit of Work and DbSet<T> is generic Repository.

Comment: I agree with everything Chris Pratt said below.  Personally I feel that the eShopOnWeb example project is really over-engineered and a bad learning example.  He creates an interface for every single class, and wires every single class up as a service, then doesn't actually *use* any of the dependency injection in his tests.  Most of his services are trivial and could have been simple vanilla classes instantiated directly, or static utility methods, or whatever.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think where a lot of developers get hung up is in thinking that you need your own layers. In onion architecture, you'll generally have a "data" layer, typically referred to as DAL. When you're using an ORM like EF, *that is your data layer*. In other words, rather than having a separate class library you create to work with the database, EF is that library, and therefore, you'd use it just like you'd use your own DAL library, if you had one.

Try not to get so hung up on layers and "clean" architecture. In truth, the *cleanest* architecture is a single project. It's only when things start to get unwieldy with that, that it makes sense to break out "layers". In other words, build the simplest unit of functionality you can. If there's a bunch of code involved, you find yourself repeating code, you have too many dependencies, etc. then start to break stuff out as part of the refactoring process. Eventually, you may end up with all the fancy layers and 100 different class libraries, or whatever, but it's folly to try to *start* there. If your app doesn't actually need something, it's stupid to add it. Plain and simple.

For what it's worth, this is probably one of the most unsung benefits of TDD, or test driven development. You write a test to ensure that one particular thing happens that you want, then you write the code to satisfy that test. Importantly, you *only* write the code to satisfy that test. That means naturally, you start simple and move to complexity. The refactor cycle of the old red-green-refactor TDD approach is where you clean up the code, abstracting things where necessary, moving logic out into reusable libraries and such. Even if you don't do the whole test-first approach to coding, it's still highly beneficial to look at development this way. You know what you need to build, so build the most simplistic thing that technically satisfies that requirement. Then refactor. Build the next requirement, and refactor again. Let you application naturally grow into what it actually *needs* to be, rather than trying to assert some sort of architecture, pattern, or process on it from the get-go.

Comment: This is great advice.

Comment: Cheers for your input. Will take it on board.

Comment: This is the biggest problem in my company as of now .. they think we will fix one way of doing and around 70+ will follow it forever which is complete wrong thinking ... they are refusing to understand that code optimization is on going process ... you will keep refactoring code one you develop it ... for my company once you done writing code its done ... you will not touch it again

Comment: Any company with that philosophy is doomed to failure or at least irrelevance. Things change, and especially in software these days, change occurs at an often break-neck speed. Your code should be constantly evolving or you're just accruing technical debt, where the interest on that will eventually sink you.